# State's `put` and `get` functions

Tags: haskell

I'n looking at the [State Monad](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.0.1.0/docs/Control-Monad-State-Class.html)'s `put` and `get`:

```
ghci> :t get
get :: MonadState s m => m s

ghci> :t runState
runState :: State s a -> s -> (a, s)

ghci> runState get [1,2,3]
([1,2,3],[1,2,3])
```

In `get`'s type signature: `MonadState s m => m s`, how does `[1,2,3]` have a type of `MonadState s m`? It's not clear to me what the types of `s` and `m` are.

Also, can you please say more as to how to use `put`?

ghci> :t put
put :: MonadState s m => s -> m ()

Overall, it seems that I don't understand what `MonadState s m` is. Could you please explain with `put` and `get` examples?

Comment: `MonadState` is a type class. No value has type `MonadState s m`. `MonadState s m` means the monad `m` supports state operations with state of type `s`. So `MonadState s m => s -> m ()` is a function that takes a value of type `s` and returns a *polymorphic* value representing *any monad* which supports state operations over a state of type `s`. `get` reads approximatley as "for all m which supports state operations over state of type s, we have a value of type `m s` - that is, the monad operation which yields the current state".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`MonadState s m` is a typeclass constraint, not a type. The signature:

```
get :: MonadState s m => m s
```

Says that for some monad `m` storing some state of type `s`, `get` is an action in `m` that returns a value of type `s`. This is pretty abstract, so let’s make it more concrete with the less-overloaded version of `State` from [`transformers`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers):

```
get :: State s s
put :: s -> State s ()
```

Now say we want to use `State` to keep a simple counter. Let’s use `execState` instead of `runState` so we can just pay attention to the final value of the state. We can `get` the value of the counter:

```
> execState get 0
0
```

We can set the value of the counter using `put`:

```
> execState (put 1) 0
1
```

We can set the state multiple times:

```
> execState (do put 1; put 2) 0
2
```

And we can modify the state based on its current value:

```
> execState (do x <- get; put (x + 1)) 0
1
```

This combination of `get` and `put` is common enough to have its own name, `modify`:

```
> execState (do modify (+ 1)) 0
1

> execState (do modify (+ 2); modify (* 5)) 0
10
```

`MonadState` is the class of types that are monads with state. `State` is an instance of that class:

```
instance MonadState s (State s) where
  get = Control.Monad.Trans.State.get
  put = Control.Monad.Trans.State.put
```

So are `StateT` (the state monad transformer, which adds state to another monad) and various others. This overloading was introduced so that if you’re using a stack of monad transformers, you don’t need to explicitly `lift` operations between different transformers. If you’re not doing that, you can use the simpler operations from `transformers`.

---

Here’s another example of how to use `State` to encapsulate a map of variables with `Data.Map`:

```
import Control.Monad.Trans.State
import qualified Data.Map as M

action = do
  modify (M.insert "x" 2)        -- x = 2
  modify (M.insert "y" 3)        -- y = 3
  x <- gets (M.! "x")
  y <- gets (M.! "y")
  modify (M.insert "z" (x + y))  -- z = x + y
  modify (M.adjust (+ 2) "z")    -- z += 2
  gets (M.! "z")                 -- return z

main = do
  let (result, vars) = execState action M.empty

  putStr "Result: "
  print result

  putStr "Vars: "
  print vars
```

Comment: thanks for this detailed answer. Why did you choose `M.!` rather than `M.lookup`?

Comment: @KevinMeredith: No problem. I just didn’t want to deal with `Maybe` for such a small example. In practice, I avoid exception-throwing functions in my own code.

Answer (score 1):

> In get's type signature: MonadState s m => m s, how does [1,2,3] have
>   a type of MonadState s m? It's not clear to me what the types of s and
>   m are.

```
ghci> runState get [1,2,3]
```

The function `runState` takes two arguments: the first is the `State` action to run, and the second is the initial state. So, since the initial state is `[1,2,3]` which is a list of integers (*), the state type `s` is just `[Integer]`.

(*) Actually, `[1,2,3] :: Num a => [a]` before GHCi defaults it, but for simplicity's sake let's use `[Integer]` as GHCi does.

Hence, we see that `runState` is specialized to

```
runState :: State [Integer] a -> [Integer] -> (a, [Integer])
```

Now, about the first argument:

```
get :: MonadState s m => m s
```

We must have `m s = State s a` because we are passing it to `runState` which requires such type. Hence:

```
runState :: State [Integer] a -> [Integer] -> (a, [Integer])
get :: MonadState s m => m s
with m s = State [Integer] a
```

The latter equation can be simplified as follows:

```
runState :: State [Integer] a -> [Integer] -> (a, [Integer])
get :: MonadState s m => m s
with m = State [Integer]
and  s = a
```

Substituting `s`:

```
runState :: State [Integer] a -> [Integer] -> (a, [Integer])
get :: MonadState a m => m a
with m = State [Integer]
```

Substituting `m`:

```
runState :: State [Integer] a -> [Integer] -> (a, [Integer])
get :: MonadState a (State [Integer]) => State [Integer] a
```

Now, the constraint `MonadState a (State [Integer])` is satisfied only when `a = [Integer]`. This is tricky to see, since the `MonasState` type class exploits a functional dependency to enforce that every monad in that class has only one related state type. This is also made more complex from `State` being a wrapper around `StateT`. Anyway, we get:

```
runState :: State [Integer] a -> [Integer] -> (a, [Integer])
get :: MonadState a (State [Integer]) => State [Integer] a
with a = [Integer]
```

So,

```
runState :: State [Integer] [Integer] -> [Integer] -> ([Integer], [Integer])
get :: MonadState [Integer] (State [Integer]) => State [Integer] [Integer]
```

And since the constraint is satisfied:

```
runState :: State [Integer] [Integer] -> [Integer] -> ([Integer], [Integer])
get :: State [Integer] [Integer]
```

And now we can see the involved ground types.

Comment: The default is usually `Integer`, not `Int`.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Right. Adapted.

Comment: You missed one in the second-last `get`.